# Issues accessing <apiroute>/oauth/token in Laravel app deployed in Azure

Tags: laravel, azure, nginx, laravel-passport

I've been developing an app. The API was developed with Laravel 8 and we use Oauth 2.0 authentication method provided by Laravel Passport.
I deployed the api in Azure and I noticed that the route that passport uses to generate the token is not working, but when I work with the api locally, it works perfectly.
I'm facing this error:
Client error: `POST https://<app_name>.azurewebsites.net/oauth/token` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response.

The app is served with Nginx and I was wondering if this could be a problem with the server config file. This is how it looks like now:

[image]

Other routes (api and web routes defined in api.php and web.php) seem to work correctly.

Do you have any suggestion? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One think that worked for me was to access to the instance in the server using the console provided by azure. I moved to the root folder and executed the command php artisan passport:install.
After that, I restarted de server and all as working fine.